# Score corruption with DRL Score rule with HardSoftDoubleScore in OptaPlanner

Tags: drools, corruption, optaplanner

Hellow.

I try to solve some optimization problem using optaplanner, some error is happened.

Version: Optaplanner 6.5.1 - Snapshot

Score Type: Hard Soft Double Score

Score Method: DRL

```
rule "Insert count collections per manager in same grade"
    salience 10
    when 
        $gradeClass: GradeInfo($grade: grade)
        $managerClass: ManagerInfo()
        accumulate(
            CollectionInfo(
                manager == $managerClass,
                $recoveryGrade: recoveryGrade == $grade),
            $count : count($recoveryGrade))
    then 
        insertLogical(new GradeStatic($gradeClass, $managerClass, $count.longValue()));
end

rule "Insert Compare total Receivables for each group"
    salience 10
    when 
        $groupClass: GroupInfo($groupId: groupId)
        $managerClass: ManagerInfo($managerName: name, groupId == $groupId)
        accumulate(
            CollectionInfo(
                manager == $managerClass,
                $receivables : receivables),
            $sum : sum($receivables))
    then 
        insertLogical(new GroupStatic($groupClass, $managerClass, $sum.doubleValue()));
end

// Hard constraints
rule "Hard Score 1 Weight And Receivables"
    when
        GroupStatic($highReceivable: totalReceivables, $weight: groupInfo.weight)
        GroupStatic(groupInfo.weight < $weight, $lowReceivable: totalReceivables)
        eval($highReceivable < $lowReceivable)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$lowReceivable);
end

rule "Hard Score 2-3 There is a manager who is not arranged collecion"
    when
        accumulate(
            GradeStatic(
                $arrangedManagerName: managerInfo.name),
            $arrangedManagerCnt : count($arrangedManagerName))
        accumulate(
            ManagerInfo($managerName: name),
            $managerCnt : count($managerName))
        accumulate(
            GradeInfo($grade: grade),
            $gradeCnt : count($grade))
        eval($arrangedManagerCnt < $managerCnt * $gradeCnt)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -99999999.0);
end

// Soft constraints
rule "Calculate Soft Score"
    when
        GroupStatic($totalReceivables: totalReceivables, $weight: groupInfo.weight)
        accumulate(
            CollectionInfo(
                $receivables: receivables),
            $average: average($receivables))
    then
        System.out.println("Soft Score: "+ Math.abs($average.doubleValue() - ($totalReceivables / $weight))/1000000.0); 
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext, -(Math.abs($average.doubleValue() - ($totalReceivables / $weight)))/1000000.0);
end
```

Here is my Class Diagram

[ClassDiagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Knhw.png)

With above Setting, In Construction Heuristic Step, below error is happened

```
2017-03-30 17:59:44,853 [main] DEBUG     CH step (2), time spent (246), score (0.0hard/-34.78590672782874soft), selected move count (1), picked move (CollectionInfo-72 {null -> ManagerInfo-0}).
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
...
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
Soft Score: 4.966641437308868
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
...
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
Soft Score: 4.967558103975534
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
...
Soft Score: 4.969724770642201
Soft Score: 4.967558103975534
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption: the workingScore (0.0hard/-34.78590672782873soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (0.0hard/-34.785906727828745soft) after completedAction (Undo(CollectionInfo-39 {null -> ManagerInfo-0})):
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) in excess or missing. That could be a bug in this class (class org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.drools.DroolsScoreDirector).
  Check your score constraints.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:378)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertExpectedUndoMoveScore(AbstractPhaseScope.java:142)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.doMove(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:124)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.decider.ConstructionHeuristicDecider.decideNextStep(ConstructionHeuristicDecider.java:93)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.constructionheuristic.DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.solve(DefaultConstructionHeuristicPhase.java:72)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.runPhases(DefaultSolver.java:215)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:176)
    at org.optaplanner.examples.collectionarrange2.app.CollectionArrangeHelloWorld.main(CollectionArrangeHelloWorld.java:51)
```

Where is my correction point?

Please help me~~^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the difference between these two?

- 0.0hard/-34.78590672782873soft
- 0.0hard/-34.785906727828745soft

Answer: a rounding error due to floating point arithmetic.

Javadocs of `HardSoftDoubleScore`:

> WARNING: NOT RECOMMENDED TO USE DUE TO ROUNDING ERRORS THAT CAUSE
>   SCORE CORRUPTION. For example, this prints false:
>   `System.out.println((0.01 + 0.05) == (0.01 + 0.02 + 0.03));`

See the documentation section [Avoid Floating Point Numbers in Score Calculation](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latestFinal/optaplanner-docs/html_single/#avoidFloatingPointNumbersInScoreCalculation) on how to work around that.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You say "Hard Soft Double Score" causes this error. Am I understand correct?